# What is the difference if I ve installed kernel ubuntu current version or kernel 3.10.4

Tags: kernel

My current kernel version on Ubuntu 13.04 is 3.8.27 but the latest kernel version is 3.10.4, is appropiate that I change to the newest kernel version 3.10.4?, I ll have benefits, troubles or nothing with this change.
I read about some vulnerabilities about kernels versions 3.8 that i think that were corrected.
I know that the newest kernel version 3.10 have more support about somethings like SSD.
Why Ubuntu (and another distros) don't use the newest kernels versions?
Some experienced programmer can change something in the original kernel and put unwanted code by anyone?
I have no problems now with my kernel 3.8.27 on Ubuntu, I just want read and learn about this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel development is independent from the distributions. The main page can be viewed from [this](https://www.kernel.org/) page

Your kernel version and its files are being served from Ubuntu repositories and mre stable because they had been tested for a long time.

If you look thorough the kernel site main page, you can see the 3.9.11 (eol) is the end of development version of your current kernel version.

After that 3.10.* mainline has been started to develop, so 3.8 main line will no longer be developed. You can stay with your 3.8 kernel or install 3.10.* but the more recent version gives more support for new technologies, bugfixed, more secure kernel (Note:Important security bugfixes are backported to older kernel versions too.)

Comment: During the lifetime of each Ubuntu release, security or serious bug fixes released in newer kernels are backported to the release kernel. Hence the 3.2 kernel in Ubuntu 12.04 continues to receive important updates despite long being out of main-line development, so there should not be a security difference.